# 2013 MacBook Pro Dedicated GPU Issues

Tags: macbook-pro, gpu

In search for a more stable and reliable system I picked up top spec rMBP (with nVidia 750m). However, quite often it displeases me when it enters some non-cooperative mode where it's unable to switch to the dedicated GPU and becomes useless until a restart. And I really can't notice what causes it to go in that state.
I would appreciate it if you could help me debug the thing.

I recorded a couple of descriptional clips to clarify the issue:

http://youtu.be/-ti2nAxb0YM

This one shows that the MacBook is unable to go to sleep:
http://youtu.be/H2F4LWa_gYY

OS: 10.9.1 (Up to date - February, 16th, 2014)

Comment: Have you tried using the http://gfx.io app?

Comment: First off, the resolution of the recording in the first movie makes the screen mostly illegible. I could tell you had problems with Photoshop, but what does that error message say? The Activity Monitor shot is completely unreadable.  What does the second video show us for troubleshooting purposes? You open and close the lid several times, rap on the lid as if doing a magical incantation, but ...

Comment: @JorisVanhecke that's exactly the app you see in the first clip

Comment: @IconDaemon, did you try opening the first clip in fullHD? It's crisp clear that way. The second clip shows that the MacBook can't go to sleep.